# Lubuntu menus appear in second language, not the default language

Tags: lubuntu, language-support

Using Lubuntu 12.04

I have set the default language to English (UK) and have also installed English (US) and Korean in that order.

I have clicked the 'apply system wide' button but some menus still appear in Korean. Some appear in Korean with some English.

The desktop is in American English.

This seems to be a bug. I can only change the menus by removing Korean altogether. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works if you delete Korean from the language support window. If at that point you set English system-wide, it has no other choice but to put the menu to English. Then after install Korean again. Don't forget to also set English system wide on your Regional Formats tab.